# Как правильно вывести дерево категорий (рекурсивно ?)

Tags: php, postgresql, orm, doctrine2, zend-framework-2

Доброе время суток.

Подскажите пожалуйста как выводить в шаблоне дерево категорий по уровням из массива объектов (Doctrine)

Поля сущности: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Category", mappedBy="parent", cascade={"remove"})
 */
private $children;

/**
 * @var \Application\Entity\Category
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Category", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * })
 */
private $parent;
```

В таблице все сохраняется нормально:

```
id  parent      name
 1   null     Категория 1
 2   null     Категория 2
 3   1        ПодКатегория 3 к 1
 4   2        ПодКатегория 4 к 2
```

Если перебирать foreach'ем то в каждой записи $category->getParent == null. (Возможно из-за того что это не просто поле, а ссылка на другую запись)
Если делать выборку в виде массива, то поле Parent вовсе отсутствует.

Zend Framework 3
Doctrine 2
PosrgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом решении всего 1 запрос к БД

```
$categoryTree = [];
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $parentId = $category->getParent() ? (int)$category->getParent()->getId() : null;
    $categoryTree[$parentId][] = $category;
}

foreach ($categoryTree[null] as $root) {
    $root->getName();
    if (isset($categoryTree[$root->getId()])) {
        foreach ($categoryTree[$root->getId()] as $child) {
            $child->getName();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Дошло до меня, что поле Parent - это не просто id родительской категории, через виртуальное поле Сhildren можно в обратку получить дочерние категории. Это огромный плюс, так как тут даже рекурсия не нужна.

Вот решение:

```
<?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
    <?php if ($category->getParent() === null) : ?>
        <li><?= $category->getName() ?></li>
        <?php foreach($category->getChildren() as $children) {?>
            <li><?= $children->getName() ?></li>
        <?php }?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Только увеличивается количество запросов в БД ((